# Can xcode Instruments disassemble using Intel mnemonics?

Tags: disassembly, xcode-instruments

I'm using xcode instruments to profile some code on my mac.

When I double-click on a function to see the disassembly, instruments shows it in AT&T syntax.

Is it possible to show the disassembly in Intel syntax instead?